# schema sys/dbo - extended stored procedure rights

Tags: t-sql

I know that sys schema has execute access on all extended stored procedures.
If my sys admin logins are having schema - dbo, what is "sys" schema used for?

Or can I deduce that sys admins have execute permissions on all extended stored procedures?
How can I prove it with tsql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sys`' is magic. Is recognized in code as special and it looks up its contained objects in the special [resource database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190940.aspx):

> SQL Server system objects, such as
>   sys.objects, are physically persisted
>   in the Resource database, but they
>   logically appear in the sys schema of
>   every database.

The ordinary ownership and permission rules don't apply to `sys`.

Sysadmins don't need any permission, they have all privileges and cannot be denied nor revoked anything.

Comment: So, do they have execute permission on extended stored procedures? how can i check it?

Comment: Check as in 'test it' or check as in 'runtime check in code'?

Comment: check as in some tsql command to say
"please show me who has execute access to extended stored procedures"

Will that be possible?

I really didnt understand your description for sys schema. Is it used by SQL server itself or users too?

Comment: I got my answer for sys schema btw

Comment: I already answered "who has access to ..." in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156812/object-permissions-tsql/1156889#1156889. Your question here was about sysadmin role and the answer to that is: sysadmins have access to everything by definition. Which is also already answered on the other post question.